# Python - 'float' object not subscriptable (GEOJSON file)

Tags: python, geojson, spatial

I am trying to extract the index of a pair of coordinates within a GeoJSON file.

**Code:**

```
coords = []
for school in data_set['features']:    
  points = school['geometry']['coordinates']
 p1 = [point[0] for point in points]
coords.append(points)
print(coords)
```

**Error message:**

> p1 = [point[0] for point in points]TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

When I run the code without defining p1 & p2 I receive the coordinates as floating points that are a nested list within a list. What do I have to do to make the object subscriptable? Also, what does subscriptable mean?

Thank you

Comment: Generally, subscriptable means that you can use `p1[index]` to access something within `p1` at `index`. The error tells you that `point[0]` is trying to access a float like that - which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

strings are subscriptable, integers are not. Please use str() function

```
newStringForSubscriptable=str(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, subscriptable means that you can use p1[index] to access something within p1 at index. The error tells you that point[0] is trying to access a float like that - which does not work.

The reason you're getting a nested list of floats is visible in this example that I ran in the python shell: `append` inserts the whole list, not each item individually.

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Instead, you probably wanted to use `extend`, which adds a list's element to the list.

```
>>> c = []
>>> c.extend(b)
>>> c
[1, 2, 3]
```

This means that your `points` is actually a non-nested list. And you could get the first point with `points[0]`